# What happened to my edit?

Tags: bug, status-completed, editing, suggested-edits

I edited [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/278668/pokemon-go-saying-not-compatible) last night to clean it up and this morning to my surprise my edit seemed to go through but not by me. I assumed maybe the OP "Reject and Edited" but then changed *nothing* (which would be ridiculous).

But no, it seems [Community rejected me](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/197659) for conflicting. Did the OP literally *copy and paste* my edit and then *edit it himself* causing my suggested edit to auto-reject? I mean, even the edit reason was the same. If not, what happened?

[image]

[image]

Comment: [This just happened to me as well](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/197807)... The edit was even approved by someone else, and the OP's copy/pasted theft broke an image link. \

Comment: @ZacCrites I just can't believe they would even copy my suggested edit reason. Why even do that? Either way, these users need to know this is not allowed or at least incredibly frowned upon.

Comment: As far as I recall, if you Reject and Edit, the box gets wiped clean, precluding that possibility. I'm not too sure how the edits happened but I highly doubt that it was done with negative intent -- much more likely that some aspect of the UI isn't intuitive enough in this regard, particularly since two instances happened in such a short time, both with new users. I understand you're frustrated, but please try to assume good faith!

Comment: Could it be a bug? Something similar happened to me where I still got the mandatory 2 points however someone else was cited as the editor, although not a single word was changed.

Comment: @CrowleyAstray Maybe, but I didn't get 2 rep.

Comment: @Insane Maybe OP didn't know that the edit was auto-acceptable, or OP didn't want anyone else's name on his question? Either way isn't right, but they're possible

Answer (score 4):

I think this is the same issue as in a question on Meta Stack Overflow: [When OP clicks [edit] while someone suggested an edit, the suggested edit gets used and the edit rejected](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332126/3853934).

> Steps to reproduce:
>
> 1. Open some of your own posts and don't touch that page until step 4.
> 2. Someone suggests an edit to your post (in this case I did it myself as *anonymous*).
> 3. Normally, when there is a pending suggested edit to your post, the "edit" link becomes "edit (1)", and clicking it opens a review pop-up
>      (you don't need [full editing privileges][1] to review edits to your
>      own posts). But the link changes only if you (re-)load the page
>      *after* that edit was suggested. So if you just keep the page open and don't refresh it, the link will still be "edit", and clicking it will
>      take you to the editor page.
> 4. Click "edit" - editor opens, but instead of current revision it loads the new (suggested) revision of the post, even with suggested
>      edit summary filled in.
> 5. If you click "Save" without changing anything, an error shows up, saying that your edit is identical to the existing suggested edit. But
>      if you change even one letter, the system happily saves the edit.

Answer (score 0):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

This bug (as [described by @MichalPerlakowski](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11904/28182)) was fixed as of [October 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355831/179041):

> A fix for this is now in place:
>
> - When you click "edit" on the question, a check is now made to see if a suggested edit is in place.
> - If there is a pending suggested edit for review, you will either load the inline suggested review modal (in the case of an inline edit) or you will be redirected to the Suggested Edit Review page (in the case of a full `/posts/POSTID/edit` page load) with a toast notice informing you why you ended up where you did.